# htmlspecialchars() why does not work on some chars

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

hi i was wondering but maybe i missed up somenthing about `htmlspecialchars()`, why does this function does not a replacement of all this  html special character
[html special chars list](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php)

cause for example the char `%` is not replaced as i can see

the php manual says about:

```
 '&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
    '"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
    "'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
    '<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
    '>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'
```

so about other chars ? no function to replace them all?

Comment: Read the whole manual page. This question is so very lazy.

Comment: This is the subset of entities that help prevent Cross-Site Scripting attacks. Notice how most of them are characters *used in building html* - i.e. characters that have special meaning to an HTML parser/interpreter.

Comment: That's because % chars and the likes *should* not be replaced by this function.

Comment: @Ispuk: No, not at all. Language newcomers are more than welcome. We just require basic effort and reading comprehension skills; you demonstrated that you have been using the manual, but you didn't read _all_ of it. Programming ability has nothing to do with it!

Comment: @reanimation so the % chars should be replaced with somenthing like substr_replace()?

Comment: @Ispuk: Why do you need to replace `%` with anything at all?

Comment: cause i need to make user ables to post pieces of code, and the % sometimes brokes like for example posting: for(i=0;i<300;i++) { if(i%80 == 1){ } }

Comment: substr_replace, str_replace, htmlentities, etc. There's quite a lot of functions to do these things.

Comment: @Ispuk: Please use `@nick` notification format, otherwise I am not informed about your reply. I am here only by vanity and chance. More the vanity.

Comment: If your HTML is ending up in [presumably] Javascript, then you have ***much* bigger problems**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) tells you everything you need to know:

> Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be
>   represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings.
>   This function returns a string with some of these conversions made;
>   the translations made are those most useful for everyday web
>   programming. **If you require all HTML character entities to be
>   translated, use `htmlentities()` instead.**
>
> This function is useful in preventing user-supplied text from
>   containing HTML markup, such as in a message board or guest book
>   application.
>
> The translations performed are:
>
> - '`&`' (ampersand) becomes '`&amp;`'
> - '`"`' (double quote) becomes '`&quot;`' when `ENT_NOQUOTES` is not set.
> - "`'`" (single quote) becomes '`&#039;`' only when `ENT_QUOTES` is set.
> - '`<`' (less than) becomes '`&lt;`'
> - '`>`' (greater than) becomes '`&gt;`'